# onBackgroundMessage is triggered but don't add event to my list ( Flutter, FCM )

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got a onBackgroundMessage function for FCM that get triggered in background has intended

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
    print('message: ${message.data}');
  }
  GlobalStream.addBackgroundMessage(message);
}
```

The addBackground message is suppose to add the message event from FCM to a list to be reemitted when the app came back in foreground

```
static final _onBcakgroundMessages = <dynamic>[];

static void addBackgroundMessage(dynamic data) {
  log('Adding background message to background messages');
  _onBcakgroundMessages.add(data);
}
```

Both of them seem to be triggered too but when the app came back in foreground the list is empty.

In the FCM doc I read that I can update data in background and thought that a simple list can be updated.

Can it be done with a list like that or need i to store them in a database or something like that ?

Thanks for anyone that can help me with that !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my probleme by creating a database with SQFLite to store my received events instead of a list

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` function when your app comes from background to foreground in the onInit() function of your page. Then retrieve the RemoteMessage from this function and then you can run your function `GlobalStream.addBackgroundMessage(message);`

Let's say your user has terminated/killed the app from recent apps. Then you send a notification to your user. When the user receives the notification, if the user clicks the notification to open the app, `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` will be triggered and then you can run any functions you like.

Comment: It has'nt change anything but i manage to make it work by storing them in a DB, the probleme seemed to be the persistance of my list or somthing.